# C/C++ ASCII Character's to HEX BYTE Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, byte

Thanks in advance

I'm wondering how in C/C++ I would achieve something such as:

ASCII Character Array:
[image]

Convert that into a BYTE Array of:
[image]

Resulting in a 0x10 array instead of 0x20.

Cheers

Comment: You mean how you can interpret the hex ASCII representations as plain values?

Comment: Yh.......... :> I looked around a while before asking but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Actually the first dump you show is a dump of a hex code and you want to encode the hex digits into binary nibbles. That's basically what your algorithm reduces to: How do you encode a hex digit into a binary nibble and where do you place the nibble (high or low)?

Comment: @TheUnknownCoder `std::istringstream` and the `std::hex` I/O manipulator might come in handy.

Comment: If we narrow it down to 1 Hex byte if I take the first hex byte as an example I want to convert the "A5" ASCII into 0xA5 so if that's what you mean yes.

Comment: @TheUnknownCoder Again, the mentioned standard classes might come in handy to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The thing is the system I am working on doesn't seem to like the lib so if their was a way to avoid using it, it would be best.

Comment: @TheUnknownCoder You probably don't want to ask for c++ solutions then. However the duplicate link provided, doesn't need the classes I mentioned.

Comment: There is no language C/C++, only the two **different** languages C and C++! Pick the one you use.

Answer (score -1):

Encoding a hex digit

```
#define HEX2BIN(D) ((('0' <= D) && (D <= '9')) ? D-'0' : (('a' <= D) && (D <= 'f')) ? D-'a'+10 : (('A' <= D) && (D <= 'F')) ? D-'A'+10 : -1)
```

and place it high or low

```
#define NIBBLE2BYTE(HI,BYTE,NIBBLE) do { if (HI) { BYTE = ((BYTE & 0xf0) | NIBBLE<<4); HI = 0; } else { BYTE = ((BYTE & 0x0f) | NIBBLE); HI=1; } } while (0)
```

. Now you can loop over your input and output with `HI=1` initially. Test for `HEX2BIN(D) > 0` to catch input errors!

Comment: Never use a macro if it can be done the same way with a function.

Comment: I just wanted to show the concept. Everyone who has learned his first lessons in C programming should be able to do this encoding in nearly anything, let it be a function, a macro, a bit of assembler code or just some plain loop directly written into the code and macros can be very useful for such simple things.

Comment: You are effectively teaching bad (and error-prone) coding style. This is read by beginners, who will take this for the normal way. You can show this also with a function. Not to forget using all-uppercase is commonly used for macros and _enum-constants_.

Comment: Macros have their own right to exist and HEX2BIN is exactly what macros can be good for. If you implement such things as a function you will get even more complexity for the parameter transfer. Using C++ with exceptions will be much more error prone in the end. Learning to deal with macros can be very useful, though the younger programmes don't seem to like them. Possibly because they all got confused by managed programming languages.

Comment: Nonsense! I did not say macros are useless! Just the usage you show here has become obsolete 17 years ago with C99. A modern compiler will inline functions like that with local linkage. And you can explicitly use an `inline` function, which will be integrated just like the macro code.  Oh, and I'm definitvely not a "younger programmer" just an older one continously learning new techniques if they improve code quality.

Comment: If this is not a use case for a macro, what else? I'm not talking about inlining of functions but of the parameter transfer. You would have to fiddle with `unsigned char*` and/or `int` here, which makes things even more complex. Post a better solution if you think you can.

Comment: Let alone the fact there are standard functions to be used for this conversion, you just don't show how you intend this to be used in comparison to a function. Not sure what you problem is with passing a `char` *`, etc., you have to use this in a function anyway. I really wonder what your problem with a function here is. Feel free to elaborate by providing sample code for both and pointing out why the macro is superiour.

Comment: try to implement it as a function and you will see.

Comment: Oh, I already have! In various languages, inlcuding Assembler and C in the last decades.